# Library for chat room

Tags: c#

I want to add a chat room for my program - but I want to use something so already exist.
There is a library out there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: our new chat room service
[chat room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276248/library-for-chat-room)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one I found:

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial239_Csharp-Chat-Part-1---Building-the-Chat-Client.html